# Check if element are in same paragraph (Beautiful soup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, text-processing

How to check if elements of the BeautifulSoup parse tree are in the same `<p>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you know both nodes are directly underneath a `<p>` tag, check equality of the nodes `nodea.getParent() == nodeb.getParent()`; more generally, search (recursively) upwards until you hit a `<p>` tag. Do this separately for each node, then compare the results for equality:

  ```
  getContainingPara(nodea) == getContainingPara(nodeb)
  ```

  (Let's ignore the corner-case of nested `<p>` tags.)
- else, iterate through all `<p>` tags, using text search or regex(es) to search for matches on both:

  ```
  pat1 = re.compile(regex1)
  pat2 = re.compile(regex2)
  for para in soup.findAll('p'):
      mat1 = pat1.search(para)
      mat2 = pat2.search(para)
      if not (mat1 or mat2): continue
      # found your match
  ```

Comment: Note that simple recursive search might be not enough, nodes can be on different level.

Comment: @liori: It is enough, I edited my answer to clarify it's two separate recursions. For each node, recurse up until you hit the first `<p>` tag (or else terminate if you hit root node).